# Erro do laravel metodo post The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel-6

Já dei uma olha no stackoverflow gringo e nada. Tentei adicionar o @csrf e todas as outras soluções apresentadas como limpar a rota por exemplo. O que acontece é que o erro persiste.

Web Route:

```php
Route::get('/', function () {
  return view('welcome');
});

Route::post('authentication', 'Login@authentication');
```

Formulário:

```html
      <form action="authentication" method="post">                
        @csrf   

        <label for="name">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <label for="password">Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
```

Controller

```php
class Login extends Controller
{
    public function authentication()
    {
       return 'true';
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o erro????

Comment: o do título. Ele não esta aceitando o post no form

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendo você fazer dois ajustes, o primeiro no seu arquivo de rotas, altere a rota de authentication para ficar da seguinte forma:

```
Route::post('/authentication', 'Login@authentication')->name('autenticar');
```

A segunda alteração seria no seu formulário. Altere a tag FORM para ficar assim:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('autenticar')}}">
```

Comment: Fiz as auterações mas continua dando a mesma mensagem de erro

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer isso no seu formulário.
Adicione o @method('PUT')

```
      <form action="authentication" method="post">   
        @method('PUT')    
        @csrf   

        <label for="name">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
        <label for="password">Senha:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
    </form>
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você esteja chamando a URI '/authentication' direto, por esse motivo exibe a  mensagem de erro. Sendo assim, terá que criar um método que retorne a view primeiro, para depois retorna a requisição do formulário.

Controller:

```
class Login extends Controller
{   
    //RETORNA A VIEW LOGIN.BLADE.PHP LOCALIZADA NO DIRETÓRIO 'RESOURCES/VIEW'
    public function viewLogin()
    {
        return view('login');
    }

    public function authentication()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/logar', 'Login@viewLogin');

Route::post('/authentication', 'Login@authentication');
```

View:

```
<form action="{{ action('Login@authentication') }}" method="post">                
   @csrf  
  <label for="name">Nome:</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
  <label for="password">Senha:</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
  <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```